# Assigning `comment()` to an R object from a .txt file

Tags: r, string, comments, line-breaks

I am trying to assign a comment to a data frame to store some relevant metadata. I have an unstructured text file wrapped in quote marks, with several line breaks ('\n').

```
WHO_comment<-read.table(file="WHO comment.txt", sep="\t")
comment(WHO)<-WHO_comment #Read in the comment from .txt due to its length
cat(comment(WHO)) #Database metadata
```

However, the readout comes in one large block with '\n' read as literal strings. Converting it with `as.character()` only returns the row name (i.e. '1').

How can I read in this file correctly?

Comment: Make sure you clearly specify your question before you post it.

Comment: It says in the title that I wanted to assign the comment "from a .txt file". This is so it didn't render as "...one large block".

Comment: Here is a link to your original question by the way. It was even unfinished sentence. https://ibb.co/5rLh7rc

Comment: Okay @Finger Picking... my bad. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read.table` is the wrong function to read a text file. As the name suggests, its purpose is to read *tabular* data. To read a text file, use `readLines`, and then paste the individual lines together:

```
comment(data) = paste(readLines('WHO comment.txt'), collapse = '\n')
```

Answer (score -3):

Solved it - I need to use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to read the file in correctly. This code now does what I wanted it to, which is assign a comment from a .txt file.

```
WHO_comment<-read.table(file="WHO comment.txt", sep="\t",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
comment(WHO)<-WHO_comment #Read in the comment from .txt due to its length
cat(comment(WHO)) #Database metadata
```

Comment: Could somebody explain the downvotes? This is the code I am now using.

Comment: As noted in my answer, `read.table` is simply fundamentally the wrong function here (a `comment` cannot be a table; it can *only* be a character vector). The solution may happen to work on your specific data but it won’t work in general, and due to using the wrong function the code is misleading and obfuscates what is actually happening, instead of being self-explanatory.